# Wont run PyGame in Pycharm

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame, pycharm

I am running python **2.7.12** and PyCharm for a school project I am doing.

I have tried several methods to make PyGame run including virtualenv and just installing it in the interpreter.

Nothing has worked and when I run it this is the only thing that shows up:

```
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7".
```

I really would like advice or step by step guide on how to run PyGame code in PyCharm

Comment: Have you tried running it from the console?

Comment: Have you downloaded Cython? Do you get an error or what do you mean with that the string shows up?